# can't set font-family or font-size on paragraph

Tags: html, css, fonts, paragraph

Hi for some weird reason I can't set font family or font size on this paragraph. Here is the code. I tried to target all paragraphs and nothing is working the text stay the same.
Here is codepen link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eHiAB as you can see I set the size to 800px on all paragraphs and its not working.

Css:

```
#about-us {
margin: 10px auto;
background-color:#FFF;
height:800px;
width:600px;
left:125px;
position: relative;
padding: 0 55px;
line-height: 36px;

}

#about-us p {
text-align:left;
padding-top: 20px;
margin: 0 40px;
}

body {
position:relative;
}

.sidemenu{
position:absolute;
background-color: #FFf;
width:170px;
height:740px;
margin-top: 10px;
list-style:none;
text-align:left;
z-index:0;
padding:0 35px;
padding-top:60px;

}

.sidemenu li a{
color:#222222;
padding: 0em 1em;
line-height: 3em;
border-bottom: dashed 1px #696868;
display:block;
}


.sidemenu li a:hover {
color:#D68D26;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body> <!-- start of the body-->
            <ul class="sidemenu">
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="">How To Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Term And Agreement</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Shipping Information</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="about-us">

            <p><h2>About Us</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  .<br        />  .</p>
            </div>

            </body>
```

Comment: Try closing your H2 tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you putting an h2 statement inside a p tag?  you should

```
<h2>About Us</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </p>
```

then your css file should read this

```
#about-us p {
text-align:left;
padding-top: 20px;
margin: 0 40px;
font-size: 12px; //(or whatever you want)
}
```

Comment: The h2 tags inside the paragraph are closing out the paragraph tags prematurely.

Comment: Yes, that is why I upvoted your answer. I just commented so the OP understood what was happening.

Comment: oh, cool I didn't realize that's what was happening, I just knew it was the wrong thing to do :)

Answer (score 0):

your H2 tag inside your p tag is causing the issue.

Move the h2 outside your p tag and it is then picking up the font-size: 800px style.